# Find the max value in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to find the maximal value in a nested dictionary,

```
data = {'violations': {'fatal': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 7, 'col3': 9}}}
```

so how to find the max value in keys `col1`,`col2` and `col3` in `data.violations.fatal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
max(data['violations']['fatal'].values())
```